# How to access help() answers from script

Tags: python, cppyy

When python is used in interactive mode, cppyy provides excellent information via python's help() function.  I would like to access these answers in a non-interactive python script.  Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want to do with the help messages?

Comment: You can redirect `sys.stdout` to a `stringIO` stream to capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jakub that your question is unclear as long as you don't explain what you want to do with the result. Point being that, yes, it's easy to capture `help()` output and that has nothing to do with `cppyy` proper, it's a pure python thing. See e.g. the example code below.

But `help` (and `pydoc`) is just using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for queries, among others, for types and docs/comments (for cppyy, those are `__doc__` strings primarily). Iow., using that module may give you more manageable results than the pure string information.

If OTOH the question is really about getting C++ reflection information as displayed by `help()`, then I refer to this answer: [Can I get the AST from cppyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262381/can-i-get-the-ast-from-cppyy) .

```
import cppyy
import io
import pydoc

class StringPager:
    def __init__(self, sio):
        self._sio = sio

    def __call__(self, text):
        self._sio.write(text)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._orgpager = pydoc.pager
        pydoc.pager = self

    def __exit__(self, tp, val, trace):
        pydoc.pager = self._orgpager


helptxt = io.StringIO()

with StringPager(helptxt):
    pydoc.doc(cppyy.gbl.gInterpreter)

print(helptxt.getvalue())
```

Comment: The problem was that the error messages I was getting from c++ through cppyy were unreadable. I wrote a crude pretty print program.  Here is the output for one line of the error message:

Comment: I was not able to read the complex error messages passed through cppyy.  I wrote a crude pretty print program.  Here is the output for